# Dual Boot with Windows: Enable numlock

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, grub

After I installed Ubuntu along with Windows, in both OS's I had to manually enable numlock (despite having enabled a setting for this in the BIOS I believe). Is there a way to enable numlock?

Comment: In Windows at least use regedit to ensure that `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators` is set to **2**.

Comment: I encountered the same situation.
I think this is a bug, and someone has already reported.
Please check this URL https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1027694.